# JavaFX - how to center JFXpopup on stage and dynamic size of popup

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

I want to make a JFXpopup at the center of the screen with a dynamic width & height. This is what I currently have:

[image: Application first look]
This is the application's first look. To open the popup I have to click an item in the contextmenu:

[image: context menu]
and after that you get to see the popup:
[image: popup]

The popup is centered on the x axis, but apparently not on the y axis. Also when I resize my stage and reopen the popup the size doesn't change.
[image: popup2]

Now for some code:

```
contextMenu.getNewLeaf().setOnAction(event -> {
            popup.setPopupContent(createRegistrationFormPane());

            popup.setAutoFix(true);

            double width = globals.getPrimaryStage().getWidth() / 1.5;
            double height = globals.getPrimaryStage().getHeight() / 1.5;

            System.out.println("stage - width: " + globals.getPrimaryStage().getWidth() + "height: " + globals.getPrimaryStage().getHeight());
            System.out.println("width: " + width + " height: " + height);

            popup.getPopupContent().setPrefWidth(width);
            popup.getPopupContent().setPrefHeight(height);

            double anchorX = (globals.getPrimaryStage().getWidth() - width) / 2;
            double anchorY = (globals.getPrimaryStage().getHeight() - height) / 2;

            popup.show(rootPane, JFXPopup.PopupVPosition.TOP, JFXPopup.PopupHPosition.LEFT, anchorX, anchorY);

            item.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Twitter()));
            contextMenu.freeActionListeners();
        });
```

`globals.getPrimaryStage()` returns the stage.
`rootPane` is the well ... the first Pane.

Here are some values from the `system.out.println()` :

```
stage - width: 800.0height: 550.4000244140625
width: 533.3333333333334 height: 366.933349609375

stage - width: 1339.199951171875height: 684.7999877929688  
width: 892.7999674479166 height: 456.5333251953125
```

As you can see these values do change, but the size of the popup doesn't change.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: TL;DR - please, explain the question - *center of the screen* or *center of the stage/scene*.

Comment: @zlakad center of the stage/scene

Comment: Just for feedback - thank's for clarification, but I am to sleepy right now. If you don't get a right answer, I promise I'll do it tomorrow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I notices that getting the stage height includes the topbar ( - [] X ). That is why the popup doesn't vertically center properly. To fix that I added `.getScene()` and then `.getHeight()`.

Secondly I now added the changed it to the following:
I made it so that the popup is created when the button is clicked. So instead of making 1 jfxpopup I just override the pointer to the popup and let the garbage collector do the rest.

```
// Option add new leaf
CONTEXT_MENU.getNewLeaf().setOnAction(event -> {
  popup = new JFXPopup();
  try {
    popup.setPopupContent((Region) UTIL
        .getPopupView(UTIL.getView("view/application/popup/FormTest.fxml"), popup));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  popup.setAutoFix(true);
  // Width & height of the popup
  double width = GLOBALS.getPrimaryStage().getScene().getWidth() / 1.5;
  double height = GLOBALS.getPrimaryStage().getScene().getHeight() / 1.5;
  popup.getPopupContent().setPrefWidth(width);
  popup.getPopupContent().setPrefHeight(height);
  // X & y axis of the popup
  double anchorX = (GLOBALS.getPrimaryStage().getScene().getWidth() - width) / 2;
  double anchorY = (GLOBALS.getPrimaryStage().getScene().getHeight() - height) / 2;
  popup.show(ROOT_PANE, JFXPopup.PopupVPosition.TOP, JFXPopup.PopupHPosition.LEFT, anchorX,
      anchorY);
  item.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Twitter()));
  CONTEXT_MENU.freeActionListeners();
});
```

---

1 quistion : When I you say `popup.hide()` does that remove the instance of that popup? Right now I just let the garbage collector do its thing. Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

You can center the popup stage over it's parent window using the `initOwner()` method, assuming `popup` **is** a stage:

```
popup.initOwner(globals.getPrimaryStage())
```

And it looks like you are creating a new `popup` each time the action is called and setting the size based on the `primaryStage` size. If you want it to remember your own sizing, you will need to save those dimensions at some point when the `popup` is closed.